# How do we send a message with Object type or a abstract class to the masstransit message

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, microservices, message, masstransit

Currently, I want to pass an object type to the message to avoid reading the DB twice.
But my solution which has the RabbitMQ is not a reference to the domain entities, it only has the abstract class and the interface of the entities.

So, Is there any way to pass an abstract class or interface to the message of the RabbitMQ?

Thank you for your advices!

```cs
public interface IDomainEntity
{
    // The rest of the code
}

public abstract class Person
{
    // The rest of the code
}
public class Employee
{
    // The rest of the code
}

public class Employee: IDomainEntity, Person
{
    // The rest of the code
}

public class RefreshEmployeeCache : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Person Employee { get; set; } // or public IDomainEntity Employee { get; set; }  Can we use this or an althernative way?
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast the message to an `object`, which should use the `Publish(object message)` overload (or the `Send(object message)` overload), allows whatever concrete type is present to be published.

Consumers can implement `IConsumer<Person>`, providing access to the properties of `Person`. The subclass type would only be available if it is known to the consumer and requested specifically.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer! <3 
I've tried to cope with this situation by the code below, but I wonder is it a safe way to use it?


 ```c# var employeeObj = context.Message.Employee;
   var employee = JsonHelper.Deserialize<Employee>(employeeObj .ToString()); 
```